# Choosing instrument played by midi pedalboard connected to keyboard

Tags: midi, keyboard-pedals, organ

I got a 30 note pedalboard (with a 5-pin midi connector) that I want to use with my two keyboards (Yamaha P-155 and Kaway CA13) to play simultaneously on all three. The problem is that when I connect the pedalboard either to the Yamaha or to the Kaway, I only get the piano sound from the pedal notes, even when on the manual I can play a different instrument. Also, the sound from the pedals is a bit louder than that from the manual (that the pedalboard is connected to) and I  barely can hear the notes played with hands because the bass is too loud.
I would like to:

1. be able to change the instrument of the pedalboard to be different from the sound of the manual board of the keyboard that the pedalboard is connected to,
2. and, if possible, tone down the sound of the pedal notes so that they don't stand out against the manual notes.

The user guides for the keyboards are here:

- https://www.kawai.co.uk/service/ca13_e.pdf
- https://uk.yamaha.com/files/download/other_assets/8/313498/p155_en_om_b0.pdf

Even though I have the guides, I don't seem to be able to get my head around this problem.

Comment: You gave us the details on the keyboards but what we need even more is the details on the pedalboard. What is it? (Make and model)

Comment: Thank you for your response (and edit). The pedalboard is made by someone, not a standard vendor, hence there is no make or model as such. Inside the keyboard, on the PCB I can see two main chips PIC16C84 and 74LS138. The rest is just a voltage regulator, a diode and some LRC components.

Comment: Actually, after some searching in my "paperwork" I found both the make (F.H.U. Muz-Or) and the model (S-30 Note Student): https://muz-or.eu/kawiatura-nozna-s-30-note-studencka-wersja-p-10.html When connected via a midi box to the PC equipped with a programm like Hauptwerk all the three keyboards work fine controlling the respective virtual keyboards. However, I would like to just connect the pedal to either the Yamaha or the Kawai, without the PC.

Comment: Further on, I found a sort of "manual" that is very.. nascent. I don't know how to upload a document here but the main idea of this manual boils down to the following: Controlling:
Press the function button F
(on the device) and then one
of the keys of the first octave:
E.g. to change the channel from 1 to 2 (ch.1 is set as default), press the function button F and then C# of the lowest octave
(midi channel+1).
The keyboard will from now on play on channel 2.

Comment: Not an answer, hence a comment. I use an Alesis Nanobass connected via MIDI to the pedals. That gives way more choice on bass sounds, with totally separate volume control. Obviously it needs a separate amp, but a cheap practice amp would do the trick.

Comment: Thank you very much. I guess it's some kind of food for thought. Though in a presentation on YT I couldn't really find any sound that would be my sort of cup that this box produces; it seems to be focused on a guitar base/band type. And then there are additional costs. I'll keep looking for a solution within the hardware listed above. Help still needed.

Comment: Maybe this will be a irrelevant comment, but I'm genuinely interested - what is your motivation behind this very idea? If everything works with Hauptwerk when you connect all three controllers, why to bother to connect pedalboard to the keyboard? If it's related to USB ports, using a hub would help.

Anyways, the only thing I can think of for the issue you're describing is that maybe changing the channel on pedalboard (by pressing the button + pressing C# for 2, D for 3 ect.) will cause the keyboard to use different sound banks